# two different Bundle objects?

Tags: android

i have question about two different Bundle object in below methods :

```
onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState);
onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState);
```

how android system know that bundle object in onCreate method is object that programmer used for save his/her activity states and onCreate method use that Bundle object to get activity state that is killed by system?
is the Bundle object one of the Activity class Members and super.saveInstanceState(outState);
save the Bundle in the Bundle object of Activity and when an activity call onCreate(Bundle ) method this member send to onCreate method?how can i use Bundle in onCreate( ) method?
please help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values you save in the `onSaveInstanceState` method's bundle will be sent back to you in `onCreate`. As an example of how this works.

1. You get a phone call.
2. Your Activity is stopped and onSaveInstanceState is called. You put a value into this bundle.
3. Android finishes your activity and destroys that instance because the OS needs memory.
4. The user returns to your application.
5. The bundle is recreated from some type of persistent storage that Android maintains on your behalf. Now your onCreate can grab the value you placed in the bundle during onSaveInstanceState

**EXAMPLE**

```
   @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.lldr_activity);

    mFilterCheckbox =  (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox_id);
    if(savedInstanceState != null) {
        mFilterCheckbox.setChecked(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("FILTER_STATE", false));
    }
}

 @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
    {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putParcelable("FILTER_STATE", mFilterCheckbox.isChecked());
    }
```

Comment: thanks
can you show me an example how can i use this bundle in onCreate method?